# Comboboxes and buttons with changing html div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have html page that has 3 buttons which on click event displays respective hidden div with form  .The html for buttons is :

```
       <button id="edituser" type="submit" onclick="toggle_visibility('c');"  style="border:0;width:100px;margin-left: 74px;">
        <img src="images/edituser.png" alt="">
        </button><br><br>

        <button id="companyprofile" type="submit" onclick="toggle_visibility('d');"   style="border:0;width:100px;margin-left: 74px;">
        <img src="images/companyprofile.png" alt="">
        </button><br><br>

        <button id="checkticket" type="submit" onclick="toggle_visibility('e');"   style="border:0;width:100px;margin-left: 74px;">
        <img src="images/checkticket.png" alt="">
        </button><br><br>
```

The js code for these buttons is:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
if(document.getElementById("c").id == id)
{


      e.style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById("a").style.display='none';
      document.getElementById("b").style.display='none';
      document.getElementById("g").style.display='none';
      document.getElementById("d").style.display='none';
      document.getElementById("e").style.display='none';
      document.getElementById("f").style.display='none';
      document.getElementById("edituser").style.backgroundImage="url('images/edit_user_hover.png')";

}
if(document.getElementById("d").id == id)
{

      e.style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById("a").style.display='none';
      document.getElementById("b").style.display='none';
      document.getElementById("c").style.display='none';
      document.getElementById("g").style.display='none';
      document.getElementById("e").style.display='none';
      document.getElementById("f").style.display='none';
      document.getElementById("companyprofile").style.backgroundImage="url('images/edit_company_hover.png')";

}
if(document.getElementById("e").id == id)
{

      e.style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById("a").style.display='none';
      document.getElementById("b").style.display='none';
      document.getElementById("c").style.display='none';
      document.getElementById("g").style.display='none';
      document.getElementById("d").style.display='none';
      document.getElementById("f").style.display='none';
      document.getElementById("checkticket").style.backgroundImage="url('images/Check_ticket_hover.png')";

}
```

The html for div is given below:

```
<div class="col-lg-6" style="display:none"  id="c" > 
                                <form action="" method="post" name="Country_Filter" id="Country_Filter"  >  
            <select name="id" id="id" class="span2" style="width:150px;" onchange="disp_div()" onchange="this.form.submit();" >
                            <?php 
                    $servername = "localhost";
                    $username = "root";
                    $password = "";
                    $dbname = "v";

                    // Create connection
                    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                    // Check connection
                    if (!$conn) {
                        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
                    }
                    $age = array();

                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_user`  ";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                       // echo "User name=" . $row["name"]. "<br>";



                 ?>
                <option value="">-select user-</option>
                    <?php                   if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                        // output data of each row
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                             $age[] = $row;
                             }
                               ?>


                <?php foreach($age as $key=>$row) {

                echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "' " . (($_REQUEST['id'] == $row['id']) ? "selected": "") . ">" . $row["id"] . "</option>";

                    ?>
                <?php } 
                   }
 else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    header('Location: webservices.php');
}

mysqli_close($conn);
                ?>
            </select>


            <form id="aa" action=""   method="GET"  >

<?php 
                    $servername = "localhost";
                    $username = "root";
                    $password = "";
                    $dbname = "v";

                    // Create connection
                    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                    // Check connection
                    if (!$conn) {
                        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
                    }
                    $age = array();
    if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])){
                     $sql = "SELECT   first_name    ,last_name,     phone,  company_id,     register_on   FROM `tbl_user` where id=".$_REQUEST['id'] ." ";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                       // echo "User name=" . $row["name"]. "<br>";



if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                        // output data of each row
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                             $age[] = $row;          

?>
                <br><br>
                <br>
                <input type="text" id="first_name"  value="<?php  echo $row["first_name"]; ?>" name="first_name" style="width: 460px;height: 50px;overflow: hidden;" placeholder="First Name*">
                <br>
                <br><br><br>

                <input type="text" id="last_name"  value="<?php  echo $row["last_name"]; ?>" name="last_name" style="width: 460px;height: 50px;overflow: hidden;" placeholder="Last Name*">
                <br><br><br><br>
                <input type="text" id="phone"  value="<?php  echo $row["phone"]; ?>" name="phone" style="width: 460px;height: 50px;overflow: hidden;" placeholder="Phone*">
                <br><br><br><br>
                <input type="text" id="company_id"  value="<?php  echo $row["company_id"]; ?>" name="company_id" style="width: 460px;height: 50px;overflow: hidden;" placeholder="Company ID*">
                <br><br><br><br>
                <input type="text" id="register_on"  value="<?php  echo $row["register_on"]; ?>" name="register_on" style="width: 460px;height: 50px;overflow: hidden;" placeholder="Register On*">
                <br><br><br><br>
                <button name="edituser" id="edituser" type="submit" style="border:0;width:100px;margin-left: 45px;" >
                <img src="images/save.png" alt="">

                </button>
                <button type="submit" style="border:0;width:100px;margin-left: 75px;">
                <img src="images/cancel.png" alt="">
                </button>
            <?php
}
                   }

}
mysqli_close($conn);
                ?>                  
                </form> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6" style="display:none"  id="d" > 
            <form action="" id="abc"  method="post"   >
<select name="id" id="id" class="span2" style="width:150px;"   onchange="this.form.submit();">
                            <?php 
                    $servername = "localhost";
                    $username = "root";
                    $password = "";
                    $dbname = "v";

                    // Create connection
                    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                    // Check connection
                    if (!$conn) {
                        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
                    }
                    $age = array();

                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_companies`  ";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                       // echo "User name=" . $row["name"]. "<br>";



                 ?>
                <option value="">-select company-</option>
                    <?php                   if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                        // output data of each row
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                             $age[] = $row;
                             }
                               ?>


                <?php foreach($age as $key=>$row) {

                echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "' " . (($_REQUEST['id'] == $row['id']) ? "selected": "") . ">" . $row["id"] . "</option>";

                    ?>
                <?php } 
                   }
 else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    header('Location: webservices.php');
}

mysqli_close($conn);
                ?>
            </select>           
                    <br><br>
                <br>

<?php 
                    $servername = "localhost";
                    $username = "root";
                    $password = "";
                    $dbname = "v";

                    // Create connection
                    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                    // Check connection
                    if (!$conn) {
                        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
                    }
                    $age = array();
        if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])){     
                     $sql = "SELECT  company_name ,acess_code ,register_on  FROM `tbl_companies` where id=".$_REQUEST['id'] ." ";

                     $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                       // echo "User name=" . $row["name"]. "<br>";


if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                        // output data of each row
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                             $age[] = $row;          

?>


                <br><br><br>





<input type="text" id="company_name" value="<?php  echo isset($row["company_name"])?$row["company_name"]:''; ?>" name="company_name" style="width: 460px;height: 50px;overflow: hidden;" placeholder="Company Name*">
                <br>
                <br><br><br>
                <input type="text" id="acess_code" value="<?php  echo isset($row["acess_code"])?$row["acess_code"]:''; ?>" name="acess_code" style="width: 460px;height: 50px;overflow: hidden;" placeholder="Acess Code*">
                <br><br><br><br>
                <input type="text" id="register_on" value="<?php  echo isset($row["register_on"])?$row["register_on"]:''; ?>" name="register_on" style="width: 460px;height: 50px;overflow: hidden;" placeholder="Register On*">
                <br><br><br><br>

                <button name="editcompany"  id="editcompany" type="submit" style="border:0;width:100px;margin-left: 45px;" >
                <img src="images/save.png" alt="">

                </button>
                <button type="submit" style="border:0;width:100px;margin-left: 75px;">
                <img src="images/cancel.png" alt="">
                </button>




                <?php
}
                   }

 }
mysqli_close($conn);
                ?>          
                </form> 

                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6" style="display:none"  id="e" > 
                    <form action="" method="post" name="Country_Filter" id="Country_Filter" >   
            <select name="id" id="id" class="span2" style="width:150px;" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                            <?php 
                    $servername = "localhost";
                    $username = "root";
                    $password = "";
                    $dbname = "v";

                    // Create connection
                    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                    // Check connection
                    if (!$conn) {
                        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
                    }
                    $age = array();

                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_tickets`  ";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                       // echo "User name=" . $row["name"]. "<br>";



                 ?>
                <option value="">-select tickets-</option>
                    <?php                   if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                        // output data of each row
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                             $age[] = $row;
                             }
                               ?>


                <?php foreach($age as $key=>$row) {

                echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "' " . (($_REQUEST['id'] == $row['id']) ? "selected": "") . ">" . $row["id"] . "</option>";

                    ?>
                <?php } 
                   }
 else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    header('Location: webservices.php');
}

mysqli_close($conn);
                ?>
            </select>

                        </form>             
                 <form action=""  method="post" id="e"  >

<?php 
                    $servername = "localhost";
                    $username = "root";
                    $password = "";
                    $dbname = "v";

                    // Create connection
                    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                    // Check connection
                    if (!$conn) {
                        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
                    }
                    $age = array();
        if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])){
                     $sql = "SELECT    ticket_no ,user_id ,ticket_status ,register_on     FROM `tbl_tickets` where id=".$_REQUEST['id'] ." ";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                       // echo "User name=" . $row["name"]. "<br>";



if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                        // output data of each row
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                             $age[] = $row;          

?>

                <br><br><br>
                <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="<?php echo $row["ticket_no"] ;?>" style="width: 460px;height: 50px;overflow: hidden;" placeholder="Ticket Owner Name*" readonly>
                <br>
                <br><br><br>
                <input type="text" name="LastName" value="<?php echo $row["user_id"]; ?>" style="width: 460px;height: 50px;overflow: hidden;" placeholder="Registration Date*" readonly>
                <br><br><br><br>
                <input type="text" name="LastName" value="<?php echo $row["ticket_status"]; ?>" style="width: 460px;height: 50px;overflow: hidden;" placeholder="Expire Date*" readonly>
                <br><br><br><br>
                <input type="text" name="LastName" value="<?php echo $row["register_on"]; ?>" style="width: 460px;height: 50px;overflow: hidden;" placeholder="Expire Time Status*" readonly>
                <br><br><br><br>
                <button name="chkticketstatus" id="chkticketstatus" type="submit" style="border:0;width:100px;margin-left: 45px;">
                <img src="images/save.png" alt="">

                </button>
                <button type="submit" style="border:0;width:100px;margin-left: 75px;">
                <img src="images/cancel.png" alt="">
                </button>
                    <?php
}
                   }

}
mysqli_close($conn);

                ?>              
                </form> 
                </div>
```

Within each html form given above i have combobox :

```
<select name="id" id="id" class="span2" style="width:150px;" onchange="disp_div()" onchange="this.form.submit();" >
```

when the user selects a specific value from combobox the html form get submitted (onchange="this.form.submit();") page get submitted and it loads the corresponding values from database .The problem that i am facing on combobox submit value it loads the initial div form .How i can make combobox on submitting value to display only the respective div with respective html form ?

Comment: Break your question down. Isolate the cause and post only the relevant bits of code please. It's too much to consume for a simple jQuery problem.

Answer (score 0):

handle form submit in JQUERY instead on click on submit.Give submit button inside each div a common class name and different id based on which div they belong. Also give each form inside div unique id according to div they belong. After that you can try this :

also define hidden input element as

```
$(".submitClass").click(function(){
var id=$(this).attr("id");
if(id=="div1") // Need to Submit form1
{
    $("#CurrentActDiv").val("1");
    $("#form1").submit();
}
else if(id=="div2") // Need to Submit form2
{
    $("#CurrentActDiv").val("2");
    $("#form2").submit();
}
else if(id=="div3") // Need to Submit form3
{
    $("#CurrentActDiv").val("3");
    $("#form3").submit();
}
});
```

so you can know which form is submitted on server end 
and you can use if else to read from particular combobox

```
String current=request.getParameter("CurrentActDiv");
if(current.equals("1"))
{
   read from comobox1
}
else if(current.equals("2"))
{
   read from comobox2
}
else if(current.equals("3"))
{
 read from comobox3
}
```

Comment: please write it with description  : read from comobox1  ......i m new in web development

Comment: sorry but you should write something like this in those loops :
`$_variable =  $_POST["combobox1"]`